# How to resolve the “Server does not support secure connections” while sending mails from remote server

Tags: c#

I am getting below error while sending mails from my webpage.

**"Server does not support secure connections"**

Please let me know how to resolve this error.My mail sending code is.Please let me know what are the possible troubleshooting ways.

```
public void sendmail(string emailaddress, string batchid)
{
    try
    {


        string msg1 = string.Empty;

        string mailLink = @"http://tk5sdatweb02:2222/SitePages/Sales%20Desk%20Request%20A%20Service.aspx?MBUP=Yes&BatchID= "+batchid;

        string strSubject = "Sales Desk Internal Bulk Upload";

        string msg2 = string.Empty;


        msg1 = "Test Email for" +batchid;

            msg1 = "<html><head><body>";
            msg2 = "<span style='font-size:14px;font-family:Calibri;'>Hi REDMOND\\v-rejinn";
            msg2 = msg2 + @"<br/><br/><span style='font-size:14px;font-family:Calibri;'>A target list has recently been uploaded they will be send to SDAT.<br/>";

            msg2 = msg2 + @"To view and/or validate the accounts, please visit the <a href='" + mailLink + "' style='color:#0000FF;text-decoration:none;'>MBUP Page</a><br />";
            msg2 = msg2 + "If you have any questions or issues, please reach out to <a href='mailto:SDPET@microsoft.com'>SDPET@microsoft.com</a>.<br />";
            msg2 = msg2 + "<br/>&nbsp;Thank you,<br/><b><font style='font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:28px;color:#033570;'>&nbsp;SALES</font>";
            msg2 = msg2 + "<font style='font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:28px;color:#7ac366;'> DESK</font></b><br />";
            msg2 = msg2 + "<font style='font-family:Segoe UI;font-size:10px;color:#3f6692;'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span style='padding-left:11px;'>Enabling World Class Selling</span></font>";
            msg2 = msg2 + "</span></body></head></html>";

        //SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient();
        SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("tk5sdatsql01", 25);
        //smtpClient.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        //MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("sarath.hits@gmail.com", strSubject);
        MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress("sdmail@microsoft.com");
        message.From = fromAddress;
        string strmailid = string.Empty;
        strmailid = emailaddress;
        message.To.Add(strmailid);
        //message.Bcc.Add("sarath.psnr@gmail.com");
        message.Subject = strSubject;
        message.Body = msg2;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        smtpClient.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtpClient.Port = 25;
        //smtpClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sarath.hits@gmail.com", "myaccountdata");
        smtpClient.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
        smtpClient.EnableSsl = false;
        smtpClient.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
        smtpClient.Send(message);

        Response.Write("success");
    }
    catch (WebException ex)
    {


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think either the PORT NO or Credentials appear to be an issue, kindly verify the PORTNo.